# Heroku: troubleshooting npm errors during deploy - reading a /tmp file

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm

Some new dependency or some other damn thing is causing npm to error during a `get push heroku master` deploy:

```
-----> Node.js app detected
-----> Resolving engine versions
       Using Node.js version: 0.10.1
       Using npm version: 1.2.15
-----> Fetching Node.js binaries
-----> Vendoring node into slug
-----> Installing dependencies with npm
       ....
       npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
       npm ERR!     /tmp/build_24pmtv04ok0ss/npm-debug.log
       npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

`not ok` indeed. There's no other useful information printed to the console, so of course I want to see what's in that log file.

So I try a little of this:

```
$ heroku run cat /tmp/build_24pmtv04ok0ss/npm-debug.log
```

However, no such file appears to exist:

```
Running `cat /tmp/build_24pmtv04ok0ss/npm-debug.log` attached to terminal... up, run.3166
cat: /tmp/build_24pmtv04ok0ss/npm-debug.log: No such file or directory
```

My questions are thus:

- Where did the log file go? Whyfor can't I read it?
- Is there any other way for Heroku/npm to give me a verbose error printed to the console?
- Why does the exact same node environment work fine locally, but fail on Heroku?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you push code to Heroku, your build is run on a temporary build dyno, so once the build is complete, all the files are gone because dynos have an [ephemeral file systems](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem). The reason that `heroku run cat /tmp/build_24pmtv04ok0ss/npm-debug.log` did not help is that that you attached to a [one-off dyno](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/one-off-dynos) with a fresh file system of your existing app (completely separate from the build dyno).

All hope is not lost. You should be able to see what's going on by [tweaking the buildpack](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#creating-a-buildpack) to `cat` out `npm-debug.log` on exit like this:

```
function cat_npm_debug_log() {
  if [ -f $BUILD_DIR/npm-debug.log ]; then
    cat $BUILD_DIR/npm-debug.log
  fi
}

trap cat_npm_debug_log EXIT
```

I haven't thoroughly tested it, but I made a quick [fork](https://github.com/ryanbrainard/heroku-buildpack-nodejs) of the [default Node buildpack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs) to [do what I just showed above](https://github.com/ryanbrainard/heroku-buildpack-nodejs/commit/984654096e954b986a191e6c285537db66bb1bb1). Feel free to try it out by [setting it as a custom buildpack](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#using-a-custom-buildpack):

```
heroku config:add BUILDPACK_URL="https://github.com/ryanbrainard/heroku-buildpack-nodejs.git"
```

Comment: ARE YOU A WIZARD this did the trick completely.  Yay Heroku.  I even learned a whole lot. BTW, the package that was griefing me ended up being `grunt-express` if anyone cares.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Just sent my change as a [pull request](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs/pull/34).

Comment: This fix has been merged into the official Heroku Node.js buildpack: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs/commit/06f629ce1d3517302f1d7d5bf89d214ef4b1600e

Comment: @ryanbrainard - very late comment, but any way to dump the `npm-debug.log` anyway (local on Heroku or remote) where you can later read it (or catalog)?

Comment: @GiladPeleg: since this was [merged into the default Node buildpack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs/blob/master/bin/compile#L104-L110), it should happen automatically on error and print into STDOUT, so you'd see it on a bad push. If you want to always see it, you can fork the buildpack and print it always at the end of a build (assuming NPM always creates on, even on success).

Comment: I want to dump it to somewhere other than STDOUT (either local in heroku or remote)

Answer (score 27):

Before you go through all the trouble of using a custom build pack, try enabling a more verbose logging output on heroku using:

`heroku config:set NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=verbose`

See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys for more information.

Comment: Wish this were a button available for failed deploys :/