# Is it possible to check log files listed on heroku build logs?

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm

so I'm trying to build an app on Heroku but it fails:

```
remote: -----> Building dependencies
remote:        Installing node modules (package.json + package-lock)
remote:
remote:        > traveltodolist@0.1.0 postinstall /tmp/build_3f0585b79822a240412a4154d454f870
remote:        > cd client && npm install && npm run build
remote:
remote:        npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded
remote:
remote:        npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote:        npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.TCdGE/_logs/2018-12-16T07_14_18_050Z-debug.log
remote:        npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
remote:        npm ERR! errno 1
remote:        npm ERR! traveltodolist@0.1.0 postinstall: `cd client && npm install && npm run build`
remote:        npm ERR! Exit status 1
remote:        npm ERR!
remote:        npm ERR! Failed at the traveltodolist@0.1.0 postinstall script.
remote:        npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
remote:
remote:        npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote:        npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.TCdGE/_logs/2018-12-16T07_14_18_095Z-debug.log
```

this does not fails on my local machine so I wanted to try and check logs at  `/tmp/npmcache.TCdGE/_logs/2018-12-16T07_14_18_050Z-debug.log`.

Do you know if there is a way? Because otherwise I'm quite blind on how to act on it.

Comment: Unfornately I could not solve it with npm. I mean I could solve it if I deleted package-lock.json from repo, but that's not really a viable solution, so instead what I did was simply switch to yarn. Problem disappeared. I'll leave the question open if someone knows how to read build logs anyway.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Heroku: troubleshooting npm errors during deploy - reading a /tmp file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15560037/heroku-troubleshooting-npm-errors-during-deploy-reading-a-tmp-file)